# PostgreSQL - jsonb - How to get the datatype for value in query with jsonpath

Tags: postgresql, datatypes, json-path

In PostgreSQL using jsonb column, is there a way to select / convert an attribute with actual datatype the datatype instead of getting it as a string object when using jsonpath? I would like to try to avoid cast as well as -> and ->> type of construct since I have to select many attributes with very deep paths, I am trying to do it using jsonpath and * or ** in the path

Is it possible to do it this way or must I use the -> and ->> for each node in the path ? This will make the query look complicated as I have to select about 35+ attributes in the select with quite deep paths.

Also, how do we remove quotes from the selected value?

This is what I was trying, but doesn't work to remove quotes from Text value and gives an error on numeric

```
Select 
    PolicyNumber AS "POLICYNUMBER",
    jsonb_path_query(payload, '$.**.ProdModelID')::text   AS "PRODMODELID",
    jsonb_path_query(payload, '$.**.CashOnHand')::float   AS "CASHONHAND"
from policy_json_table
```

the PRODMODELID still shows the quotes around the value and when I add ::float to second column, it gives an error

```
SQL Error [22023]: ERROR: cannot cast jsonb string to type double precision
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that `jsonb_path_query()` returns `jsonb` objects. If you want the contents of the object (even if it is a primitive type), extract element 0. There is no support for extracting values into anything other than `json(b)` or `text`, so you will have to then convert `text` to whatever numeric type you need.

`->>0` only works for jsonb primitives, oddly enough.

```
Select 
    PolicyNumber AS "POLICYNUMBER",
    jsonb_path_query(payload, '$.**.ProdModelID')->>0 AS "PRODMODELID",
    (jsonb_path_query(payload, '$.**.CashOnHand')->>0)::float AS "CASHONHAND"
from policy_json_table
```

Aside: Please, please, please [don't use floating point for currency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency). Your accountants will kill you over the disappearing/reappearing pennies. Use `numeric` for currency values.

Comment: Thanks.  I will test this and accept the answer.  Also, on some site, I saw they used this construct - `#>> '{}'` to get the text value, not object.  I have been trying to find out how it works.  Any idea?  Couldn't find that explained anywhere. Also, thanks for the suggestion to use numeric.  The above I was just trying to get the data as non-string